# What does (b & 0xff) mean?

Tags: java, hash, hex, sha1

With Java, I am converting a String value to a hash using SHA1 on a MessageDigest instance. I am at the point where I have created a hash object:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
byte[] hash = md.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The part I do not understand is what b & 0xff means in the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2*hash.length);
for(byte b : hash) {
   sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
}
```

I know that %02x means to specify a format where there are two characters using hexadecimal, but I've no idea what the second parameter is, what it does to each byte or what it means. A simple explanation would be great! :-)

Comment: Random side note: if you can use third-party libraries, this whole thing is the one line `Hashing.sha1().hashString(password, Charsets.UTF_8).toString()` with [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Answer (score 2):

That's the [bitwise AND operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). `b & 0xff` gets the last byte of `b`. Since `b` is already a `byte`, I don't see any point to this: the result of the `String.format` is the same.

Comment: See the duplicate answer for why that bitwise-AND is useful in the OP's  context. Also, b is a byte.

Comment: One utility of "b & 0xff" here is that it works independently of whether the format symbol is currently %02x or %03d.